# Is there a way to put images in cells in tables in iOS Numbers? 3.2

Tags: ios, numbers

Is there a way to put images in cells in tables in Numbers iOS version 3.2? I've looked at the Apple help and it only shows help for on the Mac and putting an image for a cell background.

I'm using an iPad Air 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with Copy and Paste.  It is not as simple as dragging or inserting into the cell, but it has the desired result.

- Navigate to the desired image and save image to Photos if not already there.
- In Numbers, tap the **plus** icon to add an image
- Once the image is on the canvas, long press it to bring up the **Copy** dialog and then copy to the clipboard
- Select the desired cell(s), long press and tap **Paste** or paste from the ⚡︎ Cell button
- Delete the image from the canvas

The cell can be resized as needed and the image will adjust.  Other content can be added over the image.

---

### Steps

**Add image from Photos:**

[image: Add image to Numbers canvas]

---

**Long press to Copy to Clipboard:**

[image]

---

**Paste into cell(s)**

[image: Paste image to selected cells]

**OR:**

[image: Paste image]

---

**Add text, formulas etc as normally**

[image: Add text and format]

Comment: Does anyone know if the image's pixel resolution has an effect on the placement? Should we use 72ppi at size, or 300ppi?